# iframe over Google Earth Plug-In fails with Windows Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, iframe, google-earth-plugin

This has been raised before, but the solutions currently fail in Firefox (34.0.5) in Windows (7 Pro 64bit SP1).  I want to plot an iframe over the GE Plug-In.  The following code works in

Chrome and Safari, and Firefox OSX:

[image]

but not Firefox for Windows:

[image]

Do other Windows users get the same result?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <head>
    <title>HTML overlay</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAwbkbZLyhsmTCWXbTcjbgbRSzHs7K5SvaUdm8ua-Xxy_-2dYwMxQMhnagaawTo7L1FE1-amhuQxIlXw"></script>
    <script>
google.load("earth", "1");

var ge = null;

function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance("map3d", initCallback, failureCallback);
}

function initCallback(object) {
  ge = object;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
}

function failureCallback(object) {
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload='init()' id='body'>
    <center>
      <div>
        header bar
        <br>
        ignore this
      </div>

      <div id='map3d' style='height:98vh; width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 50'></div>

      <iframe src="" srcdoc="<p style='color: red;'>Let's put some HTML on top</p><br><p style='color: red;'>And some more here</p>" style='width: 200px; height: 100px; top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 100'></iframe>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving the text the following property:

```
z-index: 100;
```

and the google map:

```
z-index: 1;
```

and give both this property:

```
position:absolute; //don't apply this property in the seperate html file for the iframe
```

Comment: Could you try to place the HTML above your map, in your text editor

Comment: Also no luck. Does this work for you? [With `position: absolute`..](http://i.imgur.com/RcP55L3.png)

Comment: The code you've placed in your original post works for me, I just added background-color:white; to the text see here:http://gyazo.com/74c1eaddde64743459a73f4e02a2d779
I'm using Firefox 34 on Windows 8, which version of Firefox / Windows are you using?

Comment: Ah, you're right once the plug-in starts it jumps to the front of the page

Comment: Alright it seems that Firefox doesn't apply the styles for the text itself, while chrome does, Firefox only applies the styles to the body of the iFrame, that's why the scrollbar is over the plugin but the text isn't, that also explains why the text is red, but won't explain the strange behaviour of the positioning of your iframe

Comment: Alright I think that I've found a solution, the issue is that you're applying the style to the iFrame, can you make a seperate file, put your html text in there, and apply the styles I've mentioned above to the body tag and if that doesn't work to the <p> tag? Loading the html in using the src of the iFrame? Currently, the iFrame clears all styles applied to the body of the iFrame and I believe this may solve it if it doesn't I'll take a look at it when i'm home